# How do you post form data using pytest?

Tags: pytest, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to write a unit test that posts form data.  The actual line in question is:

```
def test_create_request():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        app_url = '/requests/'
        with app.app_context():
            new_request = get_new_request()

            form_data = json.dumps(new_request, default=str)
            print('FORM DATA:  ', form_data)
            resp = test_client.post(app_url, data=form_data, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
            assert resp.status_code == 200
            s = json.loads(resp.data)
            assert s['success'] == True
```

Where `new_request` is a dict representation of an object.  The print statement yields (I've formatted it a bit):

```
FORM DATA:   {
    "request_id": "6", 
    "state_id": 1, 
    "orig_project_id": "1", 
    "orig_project_code": "QQQ", 
    "orig_allocated_funding": "123.45", 
    "orig_ytd_spend": "123.45", 
    "orig_ytd_commit": "123.45", 
    "orig_ytd_ocnr": "123.45", 
    "new_project_id": 2, 
    "new_funding_amount": 123.45, 
    "new_ytd_spend": 123.45, 
    "new_ytd_commit": 123.45, 
    "new_ytd_ocnr": 123.45, 
    "plan": "this is the plan", 
    "reason": "this is the reason", 
    "sm_director": "sm.dir@example.com", 
    "submitted_by": "xfgbn@vexample.com", 
    "created_on": "2021-09-14 16:32:55", 
    "meets_approval_guidelines": null
}
```

In the flask form, most fields are required.  When I try to post the data, the `form.validate_on_submit()` function in the view's route returns `False`, and the 2nd `assert` fails.  WTForms claims that none of the required `orig_allocated_funding`, `orig_ytd_spend`, `orig_ytd_commit`, `orig_ytd_ocnr`, `new_project_id`, `new_funding_amount`, `new_ytd_spend`, `new_ytd_commit`, `new_ytd_ocnr`, `reason`, `plan`, `sm_director`, or `submitted_by` fields are supplied.

I've read several tutorials, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Can anyone help?

Comment: `test_client.post(app_url, json=form_data)`

Comment: I get the same result.  No data is actually getting sent with the request.

Answer (score 0):

What I was able to make work was **scraping** `form_data` altogether:

```
def test_create_request():
    with app.test_client() as test_client:
        app_url = '/requests/'
        with app.app_context():
            new_request = get_new_request()
            resp = test_client.post(app_url, data=new_request)

            assert resp.status_code == 200
            s = json.loads(resp.data)
            print(s['html'])
            assert s['success'] == True
```